# Как отследить событие Нажатие на крестик формы?

Tags: c#

Я пишу плагин для Автокада на C#. Мне нужно понять, что пользователь нажал на крестик главного окна Автокада.

Comment: Дайте больше информации, как и что вы делаете, какие библиотеки используете. / См. [это](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/onquit-event/td-p/7773776)

Comment: Я создаю немодальное диалоговое окно Windows Forms. В этом окне есть компонент ListView.
Когда фокус находится в нем, нажатие на крестик в окне Автокада не закрывает Автокад, а только переводит фокус в окно Автокада. Поэтому хотелось бы понять, что пользователь нажал на крестик, и завершить работу программы.

Помимо системных я использую след. библиотеки:
Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

Comment: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2011/ENU/filesMDG/WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-36c9.htm - BeginDocumentClose, и есть пример

Comment: Все это прекрасно. Проблема только в том, что при нажатии на крестик окна Автокада программа в событие BeginDocumentClose не переходит.